# File google-services.json is missing. Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-services

Hello I have an error on my application, I am trying to use OTP with Firebase, I have created project in firebase and downloaded google-services.json and then i put it to the android/app folder. Also in the android/app/build.gradle at the bottom I have added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

By the way when I am removing the line above -> (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'). It works fine. But I need to use this line in order to use firebase project

and inside android/build.gradle I have added these dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // Add the google services classpath
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'   // <-- for google services
    }
```

I don't understand why it could not find the file. And still giving an error that says this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
  D:\Mac\Pan\android\app\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution, I think the problem was in dependencies so instead of this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

I wrote another version and it worked for me :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```